# How to rerender outputpanel that has Input Rich Text Area as Child?

Tags: visualforce

I have the requirement to disable the rich text are and enable it once the user double clicks on it. I tried using action support to achieve the functionality but got the following error.

Here is the sample code :

```
<apex:outputPanel id="PreviewPanel"> 
        <apex:actionSupport event="ondblclick" rerender="PreviewPanel" action="{!enableRichTextArea}"/> 
        <apex:outputPanel id="PreviewPanel_1" rendered="{!toogleRichTextArea}"> 
            <apex:inputTextarea richtext="true" id="EmailBody1" label="EmailBody" rows="25" cols="20000" ondblclick="false" disabled="true" value="{!emailTemplateSelected.htmlValue}"/> 
       </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

---

[image]

Comment: You can't rerender inputRichTextArea. Looks like you want to just display email template. correct (You don't want user to modify email template ) ?

Comment: Any other approach that can be used ,to achieve the same results ?

Comment: Chinmay you just want to display email template body in VF page ? Or user can update the email template ?

Comment: Yes user can update the email template, but I want to make it editable only when the user double clicks on the rich text editor.

Comment: ohh.. You want them to update email template... I was think you could use `<apex:outpuText value="{!emailTemplateSelected.htmlValue}" escape="false">` instead `apex:textarea`

Comment: The problem is I also cannot hide the input richtextarea with render false.

Comment: might help [custom rich text area](http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2015/01/visualforce-richtext-area-component.html)

Comment: @Tushar Trying it out mate. Did it work for you ?